# 'Overload resolution failed' when using putImageData on HTML5 canvas context

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I was going through the MDN canvas tutorial and I wrote this code which is supposed to color in red the top left corner (50x50 pixels) of this canvas.

I am getting a weird error (`Overload resolution failed`) for which I cannot find anything while googling.

```
Test002.html:35 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'putImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': Overload resolution failed.
    at draw (Test002.html:35:8)
draw @ Test002.html:35
load (async)
(anonymous) @ Test002.html:48
```

I was testing this in Chrome. Not sure what I am doing wrong... Any ideas?

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas1" width="800" height="600" style="border: 1px solid black;">

    <script type="text/javascript">

        const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        const idata = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        console.log(idata);


        const getColorIndicesForCoord = (x, y, width) => {
          const red = y * (width * 4) + x * 4;
          return [red, red + 1, red + 2, red + 3];
        };

        const colorIndices = getColorIndicesForCoord(5, 5, canvas.width);

        const [redIndex, greenIndex, blueIndex, alphaIndex] = colorIndices;

        function draw() {

            console.log("Started drawing.");

            for (let i=0; i<50; i++) {
                for (let j=0; j<50; j++) {
                    putPixel(i, j, 200, 0, 0);
                }
            }

            // (imageData, xLoc, yLoc, 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight); 

            ctx.putImageData(idata, 0, 0, 0, 0);

            console.log("Finished drawing.");
        }

        function putPixel(x,y,r,g,b) {
            let colorIndices = getColorIndicesForCoord(x, y, canvas.width);
            idata[colorIndices[0]] = r;
            idata[colorIndices[1]] = g;
            idata[colorIndices[2]] = b;
            // idata[colorIndices[3]] = a;
        }

        window.addEventListener("load", draw);

    </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error in FF is much clearer:

```
Uncaught TypeError: CanvasRenderingContext2D.putImageData:
5 is not a valid argument count for any overload.
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData#syntax) for the correct overloads:

> ```js
> putImageData(imageData, dx, dy)
> putImageData(imageData, dx, dy, dirtyX, dirtyY, dirtyWidth, dirtyHeight)
> ```

You can use either 3 or 7 arguments, but you gave 5.

I also suggest minimizing the problem--you can reproduce this with a few lines of code--create a canvas, create a context and call `.putImageData()` with 5 args:

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Fix:

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0, 0, 0, imageData.width, imageData.height);
// or ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

Beyond that, your `putPixel` function is incorrect. It's setting properties on the `idata` object, not `idata.data`, which is where the actual image data buffer is. Also, alpha should be 255 to make sure the color isn't transparent.

```js
function putPixel(x, y, r, g, b) {
    const colorIndices = getColorIndicesForCoord(x, y, canvas.width);
    idata.data[colorIndices[0]] = r;
    idata.data[colorIndices[1]] = g;
    idata.data[colorIndices[2]] = b;
    idata.data[colorIndices[3]] = 255;
}
```

That said, the design here leaves a bit to be desired. Allocating a new array for `getColorIndicesForCoord` is pretty expensive, so you might want to translate coordinates to linear array one by one and avoid thousands of allocations per frame. Of course, it's good to avoid premature optimization, but it's also good to avoid abstractions until the code is working--then it'll be clearer how to factor out functions, preferably ones that don't mutate state outside their scope.

Comment: I tried also to pass all 7 arguments, then I have no error but nothing happens. I mean, no red square drawn. You mean 3 args not 2. I tried that too. Same behavior as with 7 args.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. If you want to create a 50x50 pixel red square, why not use `fillRect()`?

Comment: Because I want to be able to write pixel by pixel. This code is just POC/test for another program which I have in mind. Btw, is this the only approach if I want control pixel by pixel?